# How can I filter a file upload by type with Perl (e.g. .png, .bmp, .jpg)

Tags: perl, cgi, file-type, cgi-bin

I am using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT  

use strict;  
use CGI;  
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );  
use File::Basename;  

my $query = new CGI;  
my $filename = $query->param("photo");  
my $user_username = $query->param("text_value");  

$CGI::POST_MAX = 1024 * 5000;  
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";  
my $upload_dir = "/" . $user_username;  

if ( !$filename )  
{  
 print $query->header ( );  
 print "There was a problem uploading your photo (try a smaller file).";  
 exit;  
}  

my ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*' );  
$filename = "user_pro_pic" . ".png";  
$filename =~ tr/ /_/;  
$filename =~ s/[^$safe_filename_characters]//g;  

if ( $filename =~ /^([$safe_filename_characters]+)$/ )  
{  
 $filename = $1;  
}  
else  
{  
 die "Filename contains invalid characters";  
}  

my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload("photo");  

open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";  
binmode UPLOADFILE;  

while ( <$upload_filehandle> )  
{  
 print UPLOADFILE;  
}  

close UPLOADFILE;  

print $query->header ( );   
print "$user_username";
print "<script> location.href='http://google.com/' </script>";
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Questions on Super User are expected to generally relate to computer software or computer hardware in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). Programming questions are considered off topic on Super User. You may want to ask this at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). - Voting to close

Comment: @BloodPhilia: It's better to recommend that the OP click on the flag link to ask a moderator to move the question. Otherwise, the OP posts a duplicate *and* the question gets migrated leaving debris here, there and yon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I filter a file upload by type with Perl (e.g. .png, .bmp, .jpg)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225497/how-can-i-filter-a-file-upload-by-type-with-perl-e-g-png-bmp-jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Data::FormValidator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aFormValidator) and for uploads specifically [Data::FormValidator::Constraints::Upload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aFormValidator%3a%3aConstraints%3a%3aUpload) .

Data::FormValidator is the way to go handling CGI params validation. You will separate your validation logic into a profile and your custom validation code will shrink to just few lines.

Comment: As of now, I cannot approve of this recommendation. See the [reviews of File::MMagic](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/File-MMagic), contains one by the author of Data::FormValidator.

Answer (score 0):

[File::LibMagic](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aLibMagic) is the superior detector. Untested:

```
use File::LibMagic;
my $flm = File::LibMagic->new;
…
my $mime_type = $flm->checktype_filename($filename);
die 'Type not accepted.' unless $mime_type =~ m|image/(?:png|jpeg)|;
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out File::MimeInfo, see: 
https://metacpan.org/pod/File::MimeInfo

Answer (score -1):

After the section where you test for invalid characters, you can compare the suffix of $filename for a file extension.  Of course, the problem with this is that the actual contents of the file may not match (they usually will, but you can't always depend on this)...

if ($filename =~ /.(jpe?g|gif|png|pdf)$/) { # --- Check for .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png, or .pdf
  # --- Supported file type
} else {
  # --- Unsupported file type
}

If you need to actually compare the type based on MIME-type-detected file contents, then that will require more processing power (Apache HTTPd provides a module for detecting MIME types which might be useful, but you may also have to upgrade to modperl_2 and use libapreq2 to access this API).

For most purposes, however, a simple file extension test should be okay.